# Altering "Send To" on Windows with Python

Tags: python, com, registry, pywin32

I need to redirect the "Send To Mail Recipient" menu in Microsoft Office (primarily Word and Excel) to send the document using a web client email. I need to do the same thing with the context menu that appears when right-clicking a file (i.e. Send To -> Mail Recipient).

I'd like to catch these events using Python, probably via PyWin32 via COM or ctypes. Does anyone know how to do this sort of thing? I'm using Windows XP and Python 2.6. Thanks!

Comment: You will likely have to register a COM component to handle the event.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the only thing I can think of is to use Microsoft Active Accessibility bindings for Python. These give you the ability to monitor events, including window open/close events. I can't think of any other library that has this functionality.

http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/assist/doc/pyaa/public/pyAA.AA.AccessibleObject-class.html

I won't kid you. This is not a pretty solution, but it can work.

here's another description:

http://web.archive.org/web/20080510165211/mindtrove.info/articles/gui-automation-with-pyaa/

Comment: I'll check it out if the PyWin32 guys don't have any suggestions. If it works, I'll let you know. Thanks!